# C# SHDocvw.dll Internetexplorer always Busy

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, shdocvw

I'm trying to automate the IE in C#. My Problem is that it's always busy.

I have a Wait-Method

```
private void WaitForComplete()
{
    int elapsedSeconds = 0;
    bool isDocumentBusy = browser.Busy;
    int TimeoutSeconds = 5;
    while (browser.Busy && elapsedSeconds < TimeoutSeconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        elapsedSeconds++;
    }
}
```

And this is one of my Methods

```
public bool Forward()
{
    if (browser == null)
        return false;
    int loopCount = 10;
    while (browser.Busy && loopCount > 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        loopCount--;
    }

    browser.GoForward();


    return true;
}
```

I tried both with the Sleep in the Method and the Wait-Method.

I have also methods for switching the Tabs or create new tabs etc. 
It's the same for every Method.

Do you have a clue whats the point of this Problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is deadlock, the browser cannot change state until you stop your loop and re-enter the message loop.  Don't wait.  Or use the appropriate event, typically DocumentCompleted or NavigationCompleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution.

The wait-method is nearly correct

```
private void WaitForComplete()
    {
        int elapsedSeconds = 0;

        int TimeoutSeconds = 5;
        while (browser.ReadyState != tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE && elapsedSeconds != TimeoutSeconds)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            elapsedSeconds++;
        }
    }
```

it worked for me like this.